# How to reset a Windows 10 laptop that can't be recharged?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, battery

A client of mine (started at a tech support job last month) got a pretty hefty problem with Windows 10 on his Lenovo laptop - the battery isn't charging anymore. It seems that this is because the USB adapter driver for the charger port broke somehow. He also reported that he had tried to install Windows 11, but that didn't work, as Windows 11 wasn't installed when he came to me. So, I'm thinking that failed install might've broken the driver somehow, or it may have been one other update that failed to install.

Now, at this point, I am kinda at my wit's end on how to solve this - uninstalling recent updates didn't work, for some reason all driver options of that port in the devices menu were greyed out, nothing was different in safe mode, and obviously a system reset can't be done because that requires the laptop to be connected to power, which it isn't. Started installing Windows 11 to see whether that would fix it, but it quickly became apparent that there's not enough battery power left for that.

So, is there any way left to fix this issue? And what would I be able to do when the battery is empty?

Comment: Lenovo battery/usb drivers issues have been around a while. There's forum posts online for fixing those. You shouldn't be trying to install Win11 until the battery charging issues are fixed. I don't recall the specifics at the moment, but I believe you can open Device Manager, delete the ACPI Battery item in there, and restart the computer. Once the driver automatically reinstalls it should be fine. If that doesn't work, opening the laptop, disconnecting the batter, letting it sit for a minute, then reconnecting it, has worked for me too.

Comment: Let me guess... A T14 or T15, G1 or G2... Lot's of issues with them. Usually takes a motherboard replacement.

Comment: If you can reboot to bios, the battery should be charging there. Also, having the laptop turned off, should charge it.

Comment: @LPChip Correct. No drivers required for that whatsoever. As long as the charging circuitry itself is not broken. Which is an recurring issue.

Comment: @LPChip Sadly, wasn't charging while turned off either. (Tried several cables, of course, and no damage to the port was visible)

Comment: "So, I'm thinking that failed install might've broken the driver somehow, or it may have been one other update that failed to install." - A driver cannot break.  If the install failed then the system wasn't changed. The laptop not charging most certainly would be a physical hardware problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had (and have) thousands of Lenovo laptops in our company (world wide) and see this problem with depressing regularity..
The G1 and G2 versions of the T14 and T15 seem to be particularly prone to this. (In my experience about 1 in 30.)
They will either not boot, or not charge.

Most Lenovo laptops, especially the business models, have a very tiny hole in the bottom panel into which you can stick a needle or a pin to press the tiny switch located underneath that hole.
This switch (press it while the laptop is without external power) will reset the charging circuit and the battery state.
Reconnect it to power and see if it will boot and charge.

If that doesn't help it is going to be a motherboard replacement which is probably only feasible if the laptop is still under warranty.

As far as I know there is nothing you can do in terms of software to fix this. It is a hardware issue.